# Передача информации из TableViewController в CollectionViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

У меня довольно простое приложение: есть TableViewController со списком друзей, в ячейке содержится имя и фото. Также есть CollectionViewController в котором также содержится имя и фото.
Задача: по нажатию на ячейку в TableViewController отобразить CollectionViewController с именем и фото того друга, который был выбран на предыдущем экране.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код TableViewController

```
import UIKit

class FriendsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var pFriends = friends
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return friends.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendCell", for: indexPath) as! FriendTableViewCell

        let friendName = friends[indexPath.row].friendName
        
        cell.friendAvatar.image = UIImage(named: friends[indexPath.row].friendAvatar)
        cell.friendName.text = friendName

        return cell
    }
}
```

Код CollectionViewController

```
import UIKit

class PhotoViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.photoName.text = "Фото"
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

Массив с друзьями в отдельном файле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте во FriendsViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectFriend", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "selectFriend", let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath, let controller = segue.destination as? PhotoViewController {
            controller.friendName = friends[indexPath.row].friendName
            controller.friendAvatar = friends[indexPath.row].friendAvatar
        }
    }
```

А в PhotoViewController перед viewDidLoad:

```
var friendName: String?
var friendAvatar: String?
```

Тогда:

```
cell.photo.image = UIImage(named: friendAvatar ?? "placeholder")
cell.photoName.text = friendName
```

Comment: Всё сработало, но при переходе появляется лишний экран, и при переходе назад к FriendsViewController приходится нажимать назад 2 раза, интересно почему так выходит...

Comment: Потому что у вас segue на ячейке, поэтому два раза срабатывает - программно и со сториборда. Уберите segue с ячейки на сториборде, сделайте его (segue с таким же названием) на весь экран (с экрана на экран).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!

Comment: Тогда отметьте галочкой ответ, плиз, чтобы закрыть вопрос.